# My cousin likes it toasty, but I'd rather not get roasted

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I am fast, but I am slow;
I am the owner of a lovely cove.
I carry on my days,
free to wallow in my ways,
until I at last don't know where to go.

I can be mean, but I am told I am docile;
some even say I am a living fossil.
A lil' tail and four feet have I,
cute, round lil' button eyes,
and a cousin who is really quite colossal.

Adam's ale is my friend;
Alas, but not for my cousin.
I'll hang out by the bay,
perhaps upon a rock all day,
surrounded by another dozen.

---

This little riddle is cadence practice.
Who wrote about himself?
Who is his cousin?
Who doesn't like the writer?

Notes from the comments:
The cousin and the writer still exist today.
The writer of this riddle is the sole owner of their cove.

Comment: Congrats on 1000 rep :D

Comment: Thank you, I made this baby riddle because I was at 999! @QuantumTwinkie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you a

> Turtle?

I am fast, but I am slow;

> Fast in the water, slow on land

I am the owner of a lovely cove.

> Turtle cove

I carry on my days,

> Long life span?

free to wallow in my ways,
 until I at last don't know where to go.

> flavour?

I can be mean, but I am told I am docile;

> Technically a carnivore I think but hardly ferocious...

some even say I am a living fossil.

> Yep.  Been around a while.

A lil' tail and four feet have I,

> Yep.  Tiny tail and 4 legs and ...'feet'

cute, round lil' button eyes,

> Like a cuddly toy wrapped in scales and a shell

and a cousin who is really quite colossal.

> Giant tortoise?

Adam's ale is my friend;

> turtles live in the water

Alas, but not for my cousin.

> tortoises don't

I'll hang out by the bay,

> where a turtle would hang out on land

perhaps upon a rock all day,

> More likely the sand but... maybe.

surrounded by another dozen.

> There's Leo and Mikey and Raph...  (and apparently turtles lay clutches of 2-12)

Comment: "until I at last don't know where to go"- I was thinking of turtles crossing the road all the time! I was also thinking of "cove" as its shell. Good job :)

Answer (score 2):

You are

> saltwater crocodile

and your cousin is

> [sarcosuchus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcosuchus)

I am fast, but I am slow;

> Crocodiles generally move slowly, but can make quick sprints when attacking.

I am the owner of a lovely cove.

> [Crocosaurus Cove](http://www.crocosauruscove.com/) in Darwin, Australia is home to massive saltwater crocodiles.

I carry on my days,
free to wallow in my ways,
until I at last don't know where to go.

> Not sure...

I can be mean, but I am told I am docile;

> Crocodiles are fearsome beasts, but behave tame enough when not hunting for prey

some even say I am a living fossil.

> Crocodiles have existed for millions of years, and have evolved relatively little compared to other animals.

A lil' tail and four feet have I,
cute, round lil' button eyes,

> Check, check, and check.

and a cousin who is really quite colossal.

> The long-extinct sarcosuchus could grow up to twice as long as a modern crocodile.

Adam's ale is my friend;

> Adam's ale is water, which is where crocodiles live

Alas, but not for my cousin.

> Sarcosuchus fossils have been found in dry areas such as North Africa.

I'll hang out by the bay,
perhaps upon a rock all day,
surrounded by another dozen.

> Saltwater crocodiles are known to conserve energy. They can stay in one place for long periods of time while waiting for currents to change.

Comment: You bring up a good point! The cousin still exists today. "I can be mean, but I am told I am docile;" rot13(zbfg crbcyr frr pebpf gur bgure jnl nebhaq; "V pna or qbpvyr, ohg gurl fnl V'z zrna"). The writer of this riddle is also the sole owner of their cove- I'll add these notes to the post. Thanks for improving the puzzle!

Answer (score 1):

Is he a

> Crab

I am fast, but I am slow;
I am the owner of a lovely cove.

> They may be fast at catching food and walking but slow at other things.

I carry on my days,
free to wallow in my ways,

> Running around the beach.

until I at last don't know where to go.

> Sure?

I can be mean, but I am told I am docile;
some even say I am a living fossil.

> They can get you with their claws, and the horseshoe crab is pretty fossil like.

A lil' tail and four feet have I,
cute, round lil' button eyes,

> Four legs and a tail.

and a cousin who is really quite colossal.

> Maybe a lobster?

Adam's ale is my friend;
Alas, but not for my cousin.

> I am not sure about the cousin but crabs like water.

I'll hang out by the bay,
perhaps upon a rock all day,
surrounded by another dozen.

> This is what crabs do.

As for "who does not like the writer",

> Well, I don't like to eat them...

Comment: The rot13(ubefrfubr peno) is not a (peno; penof unir gra yrtf)- but good guess!